# ObjectiveC: Reading Characteristics in a particular order

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I am fairly new to objective C programming so please excuse if this is a very simple question.

I am connecting to a peripheral device over Bluetooth and want to be able to read the devices characteristics in a particular order. The value(s) returned from one characteristic will determine which characteristic to read next.

Currently if I discover a new characteristic using the code

```
[peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MyUUID_1]] forService:service];
```

I can discover the characteristic correctly and can read the value. My problem pertains to if, following the discovery of the first characterisitic, I then try to discover a second characteristic using the same code as above but with *MyUUID_2*.

When the *didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService* method is called the service has both the *MyUUID_1* and *MyUUID_2* characteristics. Therefore when looping through my if loops within the method, the first characteristic gets used again.

Is there a way to clear the discovered characteristics from a service, so that the only characteristic looped through within *didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService* is the characteristic called desired by the call of *discoverCharacteristics*

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the following: to be able to read/write characteristics, you need to have **valid** instances of `CBService` and `CBCharacteristic`.

When you call `discoverServices` and `discoverCharacteristics` methods, you will get back instances of `CBService` and `CBCharacteristics`. You will be able to rely on those instances (aka consider them as valid) until the peripheral disconnects. So once a characteristic has been discovered, you can keep a reference to it and read/write its value outside the callback `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:`

If you want to be able to read the characteristic in a predefined order, you first need to operate in two steps:

1. Discover all the characteristics you're interested in for the services.
2. Once you all those characteristics are discovered, read the first one   and wait for the answer.
3. Then read the second one and wait for the answer.

One way to do it would be to wrap those steps inside `NSOperations`, you could create a new delegate protocol to help you or use 'NSNotificationCenter'

```
@protocol MyBLEProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) didFinishReadFirstCharacteristic;
- (void) didFinishReadSecondCharacteristic;
@end
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, and for the speed in doing so.

Do you mean that I should discover services and then discover all characteristics that I may require using the discoverCharacteristics call. Then inside the callback didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService just read them in the order that I would like?

Then

Comment: You don't necessarily have to read the characteristics inside `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService`. You can wrap everything using delegation or NSOperations. I will try to update my first post.

Comment: So, my problem is that the call may be FFF1 -> FFF2 -> FFF3, while the 2nd time might be FFF5 -> FFF3 -> FFF2

Comment: Discover the characteristics in a loop. Stash the ones your are interested in in some collection. (dict, set, array) When you have aggregated all the characteristics you are interested in, break out of the loop and proceed to read and write the characteristics as you deem necessary.